# Don't want ASP.net escape my string from database

Tags: asp.net

I have a field with product name

```
abc&reg; product1
```

If I get the data from the database and databind it to the dropdownlist. It becomes

```
<option value="2">abc &amp;reg;  product1</option>
```

I don't want ASP.net to escape the `&reg;` to `%amp;reg`.
What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to [HTML encode](http://dotnetperls.com/encode-html-string) the string prior to it being shown in the HTML.  This will preserve its name

Answer (score 1):

i'm using such thing (see below), maybe it will help you

first i'm encoding data (special symbols) in **numeric entites**, when push data in database

when i receive it from database, i write such thing in View:

```
<% =Html.TextBox("test", Model.test).ToString().Replace("&amp;#", "&#")%>
```

point is, that when you writing `Model.test`, that actually means `Html.Encode(Model.test)`

in my case i don't want to simly decode it (because it could be XSS for example), but write only correct data to input value

Answer (score 0):

In your database you shouldn't store `abc&reg; product1` but `abc® product1`. Then when this value is rendered on the page you need to HTML encode it which happens automatically if you use `<asp:DropDownList`.

Comment: I cannot change the database data. What should I do? Encode the string again in databinding method?

Comment: @m.edmondson, that's exactly what I suggested in my answer. Did you read it carefully? Quote: `In your database you shouldn't store abc&reg; product1 but abc® product1`. Maybe I should have bolded **shouldn't**.

Comment: ® isn't valid HTML whereas abc&reg; is

Comment: @m.edmondson, yes but that's what you should store in your database. When time comes to show this data you will HTML encode it. You should **never** store `abc&reg;` in a database unless you want to tie this database to a web application only. What happens if you wanted to use it in a Windows Application? Or perform searches on the values? Also `®` is a perfectly valid HTML if your page is `utf-8` encoded. I would recommend you to use the [W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/) and see it for yourself.

Comment: @m.edmondson, I would have edited my question if it was to bring some value or modify it because it contains wrong information. None being the case I have no intention of editing for the sake of a vote. So next time make sure you've properly read an answer before casting a downvote.

Comment: @Darin - Apologies but since most things allow you to edit you would think I would be allowed to change my mind about a downvote after thinking about it for a while

Answer (score 0):

As the above person mentioned, abc® is a REALLY bad feild name.
Does it HAVE to be that?

Comment: Why is it bad? It's a legitimate string representing a registered trademarked name, just stored in slightly the wrong way.

Comment: Opps I didn't mean for it to acually show the (r) symbol but it did. What are you trying to do? Because you have a "Field" with one value in it, but you're puting it in a DropDown control?